# Postgres 9.4 restore not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I do a backup of postgresql 9.4 database as per the postgres doc of WAL archiving.

After backup I create 2 records in DB.

Now when I try to restore the DB, the last 2 records which I created above is not coming up.

**WAL archive steps:**

```
cd /etc/postgresql/9.4/
mkdir archives
mkdir backups
chown postgres:postgres archives
chown postgres:postgres backups
cd /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/
echo 'max_wal_senders=1' >> postgresql.conf
echo 'wal_level=hot_standby' >> postgresql.conf
echo 'archive_mode=on' >> postgresql.conf
echo "archive_command='test ! -f /etc/postgresql/9.4/archives/%f && cp %p /etc/postgresql/9.4/archives/%f'" >> postgresql.conf
echo 'local replication postgres trust' >> pg_hba.conf
service postgresql restart
```

**Backup steps:**

```
cd /etc/postgresql/9.4/backups
rm -rf *
pg_basebackup --xlog -U postgres --format=t -D /etc/postgresql/9.4/backups/
```

**Restore steps:**

```
 service postgresql stop
 cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/
 if [ ! -d "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/tmp/" ]
 then
    mkdir tmp
  else
    rm -rf tmp
  fi
  mkdir tmp
   mv /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/* /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/tmp/
  cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/
  rm -rf *
   cd /etc/postgresql/9.4/backups
  tar -xf base.tar -C /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/
 cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/

 FROMDIR="/etc/postgresql/9.4/archives/"

 TODIR="/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/tmp/pg_xlog/"

 if [ ! -d "$FROMDIR" ]
 then
      echo "Directory $FROMDIR does not exist!!"
 exit
 fi


 if [ ! -d "$TODIR" ]
 then
        echo "Directory $TODIR does not exist!!"
        exit
  fi

  cd $FROMDIR

  for i in `find . -type f`
      do
         if [ ! -f $TODIR/$i ]
      then
      echo "copying file $i"
      cp $i /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_xlog/$i
      fi

     done

   cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_xlog/

   chown -R postgres:postgres *

   cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/

   FILE="recovery.done"

   if [ -f $FILE ]
   then
          mv $FILE recovery.conf
   else
         echo "restore_command = 'cp /etc/postgresql/9.4/archives/%f %p'" >> recovery.conf
   fi

   su postgres service postgresql start

   exit
```

Comment: Show your restore script, if not using pgAdmin or smilar ones to do the task

Comment: Details? exact steps taken. Log files. Commands run. etc.

Comment: I do a backup before creating 2 records and I expect that recent WAL archive files should restore the latest 2 records....isnt that the whole concept of WAL archive recovery?

Comment: @Ashok Edit the question to add more info please - see the "edit" button on the bottom left below the tags. Makes it more readable. You can delete the comments. Might be worth taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @CraigRinger Updated....Please check

Comment: @Vivek.S Any suggestions please?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the archives get copied from master to replica. Is there a shared NFS volume involved? Also, what's in the log files on the replica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes appear in archive (/etc/postgresql/9.4/archives/ in your case) when the current WAL segment (usually 16 Mb) is filled up. Let me quote the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-wal.html):

> The archive_command is only invoked for completed WAL segments. Hence,
>   if your server generates little WAL traffic (or has slack periods
>   where it does so), there could be a long delay between the completion
>   of a transaction and its safe recording in archive storage. To limit
>   how old unarchived data can be, you can set archive_timeout to force
>   the server to switch to a new WAL segment file periodically. When this
>   parameter is greater than zero, the server will switch to a new
>   segment file whenever this many seconds have elapsed since the last
>   segment file switch, and there has been any database activity,
>   including a single checkpoint. (Increasing checkpoint_timeout will
>   reduce unnecessary checkpoints on an idle system.) Note that archived
>   files that are closed early due to a forced switch are still the same
>   length as completely full files. Therefore, it is unwise to use a very
>   short archive_timeout — it will bloat your archive storage.

If you just want to test the restore process, you can simply do `select pg_switch_xlog();` after creating some records to force switch to a new WAL segment. Then verify that a new file appeared in the archive directory.

---

Also, you need not copy files from the archive directory to pg_xlog/. `Restore_command` will do it for you.

Comment: So are you suggesting that after I create records, I should do a pg_switch_xlog to get archives ?

Comment: Also, I do not see a new archive file after force switch @Egor Rogov

Comment: Switch occurs when next change is made after pg_switch_xlog(). Insert another record and check the archive directory again.

Comment: Ok. My major concern is should I have this in my production system, as the issue will happen only if there is little traffic. Is there  a industry standard?

Comment: No, it's not for production, just for testing. Don't know about industry standard, but you may wish to set `archive_timeout` parameter in case your system experiences periods of little traffic.